# How to use PHP MySQLi to get number of rows and use mysql_fetch_array() for prepared statments using the procedural method?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am attempting to relearn PHP, SQL, HTML, CSS and JS because it has been 2 years since I last learn it at Uni.

I have the following mysqli statements which either doesnt properly work, or produces a strange result:

**UPDATE**
Below is the code in my connectdb.php file:

```
   <?php

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "testdatabase";

    $dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Please just assume all undefined variables have been defined already, the problem i promise is not related to syntax, but rather to the mysqli module, which after switching to use the prepared statement method has become a little bit more difficult.

```
<?php
$sub_signin_email = $_POST["signin_email"];

require("connectdb.php");
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`= ? ";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);

if ($stmt){

    $bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $sub_signin_email);
    if (!$bind){ echo "Error! Unable to bind stmt <br/>"; }

    $exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (!$exec){ echo "Error! Unable to execute stmt <br/>"; }

    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $stored_result = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    $num_of_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>User Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>FName</th>
            <th>LName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Account_Type</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody> 
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $userId = $row['user_id'];
        $title = $row['Title'];
        $Fname = $row['FName'];
        $Lname = $row['LName'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $password = $row['password'];
        $account_type = $row['account_type'];
        $status = $row['status'];

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> $userId </td>";
        echo "<td> $title </td>";
        echo "<td> $Fname </td>";
        echo "<td> $Lname </td>";
        echo "<td> $email </td>";
        echo "<td> $password </td>";
        echo "<td> $account_type </td>";
        echo "<td> $status </td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);     
?>
```

after hours of research online, I have come to the above final solution, however although it works, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);`, always seems to return 0 regardless of there being several records or no records.

To overcome this I found that I need to only use `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);`, which once used helps the `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);` work properly, however it causes errors when it reaches the point of processing `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. For this case I receive an error such as: `mysqli_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, boolean given**

Alternatively when I only use `mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);`, it executes everything however, it also shows the number of rows as 0.

Please do not ask me to start using PDO, I am currently only looking to use what I know, which is MySQLi, I tried to use PDO, however as I am not good with OOP, I found it hard to use.

Thank you very much :D.

Comment: `require("connectdb.php);` is that a typo? If so, it's throwing off syntax highlighting.

Comment: `$sub_signin_email` where is this assigned? and why aren't you using proper error handling?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes sorry it was typo here on this post, the code works fine, its just getting it to inform me of how many rows my querry found, is what is giving me an issue mainly.

Comment: you need to find out why your query failed by using `mysqli_error($dbc)`.  The *mysqli_fetch_array()** expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given* means that your query failed. Either by the connection and/or the query itself. PHP's error reporting is also something that should be used.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner just assume its defined. actually let me add it to the top of the script.

Comment: @FunkyFortyNiner on my script, I have set mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);, which should automatically break or stop the script should an error be detected, to identify out the cause of the issue

Comment: Wait I got down voted?, why? I have asked a reasonable question, which I am trying to solve the whole day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, spent almost 5+ hours today looking for a solution, and finally I get it, feel so ashamed because the solution was so simple.

Because I am new to creating prepared statements using mysqli, I thought I only could use procedures related to it (i.e. procedures that contained stmt within their function name), therefore 1 such function I was too focused on trying to get working was:

```
$num_of_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

**Using the `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` approach:**

So far I was forced to use `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);`, in order for `mysqli_stmt_num_rows` above to return me the correct number of rows returned from a query. However, using this `mysqli_stmt_store_result()` procedure led to me experience errors when i attempted to perform `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

**Using the `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` approach:**

Because I was unable to fetch the data, I search online and found an alternative procedure, which was `mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);`, now this function enable me to fetch `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` without issues, which allowed me to access the returned values from the query and manipulate them as I pleased. However, when using this approach `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);` always returned 0 regardless of the number of matching items that my query found from the database.

### Solution Found After Hours of Searching

In order to find the number of rows that a query has found using:

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
```

Was, instead of using:

```
$num_of_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

All i had to use was:

```
$num_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

And finally now this works. It returns the total number of rows returned from a query and also allows me to use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` to fetch and manipulate the row items returned from my query.

Also by using this approach I no longer require the need for using:

```
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
```

To fetch data from my database using mysqli.

Sorry for the lengthy answer, I have searched for a solution for hours online, and nowhere did I find a proper solution, and therefore I hope this may help anyone else facing a similar issue.

Thank you every one that helped me here and in chat to try and find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that fetch assoc will be better for you. You are using the column names, and using a while() loop, so you have no need to navigate the result data numerically (outside of knowing how many there are)...

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$stored_result = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
$num_of_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
if($num_of_rows > 0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // declare variables (ex: $user = $row['user'])
 }
} else {
 echo "<tr><td colspan='8'>No results found...</td></tr>"; 
}
```

Let me know if that works for you... There's no visible reason that your attempts are failing, but without being able to see your db connection variable var dump, or similar methods of bug testing, it's going to be hard to help you.

Can you try echoing out some sql errors?

If nothing works, do this if you don't need the # of rows until the end...

```
$numResults = 0; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 // Declare variables 
 $numResults++; 
}
echo $numResults; // number of rows found, after loop
```

Comment: thankyou very much for the detailed solution, just attempted your first solution, and it works, the same way as mine worked, however mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);, still returns as 0, look at the screenshot on the link https://ibb.co/dJKRZx, which shows the table result and what num_of_rows shows

Comment: And you have just this right? ... echo $num_of_rows; can you please paste your full codeblock on pastebin

Comment: Ok your second solution works to retreive the number of rows, but it would require me to run the loop for retreiving the data, which would make it less practical as I move on from this sign in page. Also here is the code on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/a9XmzEWc

Comment: If you have access to chat.stackoverflow.com, I am currently online there at the PHP room, if you would like to discuss better.